# Android ProgressDialog inside another dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog, progressdialog

I'm working on a game using AndEngine, and I need to show the users the list of his Facebook friends.
I've created my custom `Adatper` for the `ListView` and after the loading finishes everything works great.
I have a problem with the loading part it self.

The `ListView` is inside a custom dialog, So inside this dialog, I'm running an `AsyncTask` to fetch the friends' info, in that `AsyncTask` I have a `ProgressDialog`. The problem is, the `ProgressDialog` shows up behind the dialog that contains the to-be list (which while loading, is just the title).
I can see the `ProgressDialog` "peeking" behind that dialog..
Any Ideas?

Here's some code:

`FriendsDialog.java`

```
private ProgressDialog dialog;

//Constructor of the AsyncTask
public FriendsLoader(Context context) {
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait..\nLoading Friends List.");
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    dialog.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading, null));
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait..\nLoading friends.");
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data) {
    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(context, data);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {
            String id = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt);
            listener.onUserSelected(id);
            dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but when I am reading problems like "Android ProgressDialog inside another dialog" my brain began to boil. I think you are generating evil things. My advice: try to think correct, and do things the way they must be done.

Comment: at first I wanted to do this using AndEngine alone, but couldn't find how.. so I'm going with this. It's really not that complicated. A dialog with a list, should have loading indicator while loading data..

Comment: Why don't you use a ProgressBar, or something like that, as the content of your Dialog ? Then when loading is finished just change its content and replace it with your ListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening a dialog from another dialog is not the best idea, especially if one of them is a progress dialog (try to rotate the screen..).

I suggest a better approach:

The friends dialog will have 2 views: ListView and a ProgressBar. 
The ListView will be invisible when you load the data, and the ProgressBar will be visible at the time. When you'll finish loading the data, just switch the visibility between those 2 views.

For a smoother transition between those views, you can use [ViewAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html), which takes care of the visibility modes and even allows you to add an effect to the transition (e.g. fade, slide etc.). It's very simple to use and there are lots of examples online.

Best of luck!

Comment: Great answer. It works even better than I expected! Thanks. Will give the bounty when it will allow me (13 hours from now)

Answer (score 0):

Use Activity as a dialog by setting style(in manifest). and than you can use Progress Dialog inside that activity